# Cannot find EditText from FragmentActivity

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am trying to save all the information entered from all EditTexts in each of my 3 Fragments. I am trying to get these information from an option button in my ActionBar.

I noticed that it cannot find the views when I am on a different tab.

My first fragment/ first tab:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:tag="gen_info">

<LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scrollbars="vertical">

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Admin Account"
        android:id="@+id/isAdmin" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/code"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:hint="@string/code"
        android:ems="10"
        android:width="150dip" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:hint="@string/fullname" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/address"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:hint="@string/address"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dip" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
        android:inputType="date"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/birthdate"
        android:hint="Birthdate (mm/dd/yyy)" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/mobile"
        android:hint="Mobile No" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/workPhone"
        android:hint="Work Phone" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/email"
        android:hint="Email" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/gender_options"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/civil_status"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="date"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/hired_date"
        android:hint="Hired Date (mm/dd/yyyy)" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/location"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:hint="Location" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/position"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/department"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

My 2nd Fragment / tab

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:tag="contacts">

<LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scrollbars="vertical">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/contactName"
        android:hint="Name"
        android:paddingTop="5dip" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/contactRelationship"
        android:hint="Relationship"
        android:paddingTop="5dip" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPostalAddress"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/contactAddress"
        android:hint="Address"
        android:paddingTop="5dip" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="phone"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/contactPhoneNo"
            android:hint="Phone Number"
            android:paddingTop="5dip" />

        <Spinner
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/contactPhoneTypeSpinner"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/contactPhoneNo"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/contactPhoneNo"
            android:paddingTop="5dip" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="107dp"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/contactSpecialNotes"
        android:paddingTop="5dip"
        android:hint="Write special notes here" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Add to list"
        android:id="@+id/addContact" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Contacts List"
        android:id="@+id/contactsHeader"
        android:editable="false" />

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/contactsTableLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dip"></TableLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

My 3rdfragment / tab:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:tag="latest_wage">

<LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scrollbars="vertical">


    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="date"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/latestWageDate"
        android:hint="Date" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/latestWageNote"
        android:hint="Note" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/latestWageRate"
        android:hint="Rate (PHP)" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Add Rate"
        android:id="@+id/btnAddRate" />

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/latestWageTableLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:paddingTop="5dip"></TableLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I declared my first Fragment's elements here:

```
public static class LaunchpadSectionFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_section_launchpad, container, false);

        Spinner spinner = (Spinner) rootView.findViewById(R.id.gender_options);
        Spinner civilStatusSpinner = (Spinner) rootView.findViewById(R.id.civil_status);
        Spinner positionSpinner = (Spinner) rootView.findViewById(R.id.position);
        Spinner departmentSpinner = (Spinner) rootView.findViewById(R.id.department);

        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    }
}
```

Here's the function for my ActionBar:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            this.finish();
            return true;
        case R.id.action_save:

            EditText code = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.code);
            EditText name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
            EditText address = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.address);
            EditText birthDate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.birthdate);
            EditText mobile = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.mobile);
            EditText workPhone = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.workPhone);
            EditText email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
            Spinner gender = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.gender_options);
            Spinner civilStatus = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.civil_status);
            EditText hiredDate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.hired_date);
            EditText location = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.location);
            Spinner departmentId = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.department);
            CheckBox isAdmin = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.isAdmin);

            return true;
        case R.id.action_discard:
            this.finish();
            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

All the Views would return null, these views are found on the first fragment. When I did not make the lat two fragments, I could find the views.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: declaring elements should be placed in oncreate or onCreateView

Comment: You have to inflate the layout in the `onCreateView` and then you can "find" all the views there.

Comment: I did declare the elements in my Fragment's onCreateView method, but also I want to access the values of those elements (from all fragments) when I click on the ActionBar button.

Comment: ** Added declaration part

Comment: So why not making a public method in your fragment to get the value from your EditText.

Comment: I've thought of that @soma-web but how exactly do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On approach could be to handle your itemMenuClick in our Fragment itself. So you can handle them in your Fragment and get the Information you need: [TUTORIAL](http://www.grokkingandroid.com/adding-action-items-from-within-fragments/)

The other approach is to keep a Instance of all of your Fragments in your MainActivity globally and ask your Fragment for the values eg:

```
MainActivity:

Fragment1 _fragment1;
onCreate(..){
   _fragment1 = new Fragment1();
}

onMenuItemSelected(....){

   String test = _fragment1.getCustomText();
}


Fragment1:

EditText _test;

onCreate(...){

  _test = _root.findViewById(R.id.et_test);
}


public String getCustomText(){
   return _test.getText().toString();
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the idea, I didn't use your code, I made a static variable in my Fragment's class to hold the view.

Answer (score 0):

Try given code

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            this.finish();
            return true;
        case R.id.action_save:

            EditText code = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.code);
            EditText name = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.name);
            EditText address = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.address);
            EditText birthDate = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.birthdate);
            EditText mobile = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.mobile);
            EditText workPhone = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.workPhone);
            EditText email = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.email);
            Spinner gender = (Spinner) getView().findViewById(R.id.gender_options);
            Spinner civilStatus = (Spinner) getView().findViewById(R.id.civil_status);
            EditText hiredDate = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.hired_date);
            EditText location = (EditText) getView().getView().findViewById(R.id.location);
            Spinner departmentId = (Spinner) getView().findViewById(R.id.department);
            CheckBox isAdmin = (CheckBox) getView().findViewById(R.id.isAdmin);

            return true;
        case R.id.action_discard:
            this.finish();
            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```